# G++ Trouble compiling litecoin on ubuntu server AMD64 (Version 16.04 Xenial)

Tags: litecoin, compiling, c++

I've been trying to compile litecoin for some time but keep getting an area that reads

```
(/home/User/Downloads/Litecoin/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a: error adding symbols: Malformed archive
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile.unix:193: recipe for target 'Litecoin' failed
make: *** [Litecoin] Error 1)
```

All help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this when building litecoin's current master on an Ubuntu 16.04 VM. Could you try `make clean && make` ?

Comment: Hello, I reinstalled all the necessary dependencies, enabled my virtual machine, and attempted to recompile it. Works just fine now. Thank you again, sir!